# Can't use group by in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am learning how to use `Group By` in SQL Server and I am trying to write a Query that would let me get all the information from Alumns in a table in numbers.

My table is like the following:

```
 Name | Alumn_ID | Course | Credits | Passed
 Peter    1         Math       2        YES
 John     2         Math       3        YES
 Thomas   3         Math       0        NO
 Peter    1        English     3        YES
 Thomas   2        English     2        YES
 John     3        English     0        NO
```

The result I want is the following one:

```
Alumn | Total_Credits | Courses | Passed | Not_Passed
Peter        5             2         2          0
John         5             2         2          0
Thomas       0             2         0          2
```

I know that I have to use `Group By` and `COUNT` but I'm stuck since I'm a beginner, I really don't know how can I separate `Passed` and `Not_Passed` in the result from the PASSED column in the table, thanks in advance

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  You should show what you have attempted.

Comment: What does reprobated mean?

Comment: You might want to use case, something like `sum(case when Passed = 'YES' then 1 else 0 end)`

Comment: you don't have to use GROUP BY, PARTITION BY is another option. Show us an attemp and we'll help!

Comment: Please re-check the values of your tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT t.id, t.name AS alum,
SUM(credits) AS total_credits,
COUNT(*) AS courses,
SUM(CASE WHEN Passed = 'YES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Passed,
SUM(CASE WHEN Passed = 'NO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Reprobated
FROM t
GROUP BY t.id, t.name
```

I assume reprobated means not passed.

Comment: I would suggest grouping by the Id and not the name.

Comment: Fair. The OP wants the name in the output though, so perhaps both.

Comment: @user7396598 If `t.name` is going to be in the output, he *must* group by `t.name` in SQL Server.  If not, he'll get the error "Column 't.name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."  SQL Server doesn't do any internal checks to see if a query is implicitly deterministic; it just errors when it isn't explicitly so.

Comment: You should use Id and Name.  Name is not going to be unique in any real world system.  I'm glad kbball got it despite my poor wording.

Answer (score 1):

The example below will do that like you solicited.

```
create table Alumns
(
    Name varchar(30) not null
   ,Alumn_Id int not null
   ,Course varchar(30) not null
   ,Credits int not null
   ,passed varchar(3) not null
)
GO

insert into Alumns
(Name, Alumn_ID, Course, Credits, Passed)
values
 ('Peter', 1, 'Math', 2, 'YES')
,('John', 2, 'Math', 3, 'YES')
,('Thomas', 3, 'Math', 0, 'NO')
,('Peter', 1, 'English', 3, 'YES')
,('John', 2, 'English', 2, 'YES')
,('Thomas', 3, 'English', 0, 'NO')
GO



select al.Alumn_Id,al.Name
, Sum(al.Credits) as [Total Credits]
, Count(al.Course) as Courses
, Sum(case al.passed when 'YES' then 1 else 0 end) as Passed
, Sum(case al.passed when 'NO' then 1 else 0 end) as [Not Passed]
from dbo.Alumns al
group by al.Alumn_Id, al.Name
```

but note you will get an error because you data is incorrect.
Look at your own example where John and Peter are with wrong Ids for the Math/English rows.

That way you will never end with the correct result and that's why it's a good practice to group by Ids.

**Edit**
I see you corrected your example data yes that way will fetch the exact results you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate `Passed` and `Not_Passed` using a `CASE` function.

```
SELECT MAX([name]) AS [Name],
SUM(Credits) AS Total_Credits, 
COUNT(Course) AS Courses, 
SUM(CASE WHEN Passed='Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Passed,
SUM(CASE WHEN Passed='No' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Not_Passed
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Alumn_ID
```

However, I do not think that values of your tables (both table) are correct. Please check them again. For example, according to your table, John has two Alumn_IDs (both 2 and 3). If these are two different Johns, then your desired outcome should be changed.

Result

```
+--------+---------------+---------+--------+------------+
|  Name  | Total_Credits | Courses | Passed | Not_Passed |
+--------+---------------+---------+--------+------------+
| Peter  |             5 |       2 |      2 |          0 |
| John   |             3 |       1 |      1 |          0 |
| Thomas |             2 |       3 |      1 |          2 |
+--------+---------------+---------+--------+------------+
```